# Unsharing a field on Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I am having a sitecore template with 5 layers of inheritance. At the top of the inheritance tree, there is a shared field and I want to override it to an unshare field. Meanwhile the only way I can think of is cloning the whole inheritance tree templates which is not an efficient way since I just want to unshare one field and keep the rest 100% the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Fields are unique. Even if you create a new field with the same name on any tier of your template tree, it will be a field on it's own, with its own unique Field ID.

Besides, templates aren't classes. There is no real concept of overriding and inheritance, although the system may make it seem like it at times.

Comment: Thx Mark, very clear explanation. So I will find some work around such as making one extra field or override on front-end

Comment: Just a side note for those who, like me, use the "Title" of a Field to add helper text for the user: the same principles that Mark mentions here still apply. There is, unfortunately, no way to override the value of that "Title" on the same field so it displays differently on inherited templates.